# How to select random characters in a non-unique way

Tags: python, authentication, random

Alright, I have a password generator, The code I have is this:

```
password=random.sample(chars,letters) #chars is a list of Characters (symbols,letters,numbers) and letters is how many letters are in the password
divider = ""
password = divider.join(password) 
print(password,flush=True, end=inbetween) #inbetween is where the user can choose what character seperates the passwords (it can print multiple passwords)
```

The issue I have is that `random.sample` only selects unique characters. Is there an alternative function that does the same as `random.sample`, but can select non-unique characters from the list.

By the way, Here is the values for the variable chars:

```
chars= ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z","A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z","$","%","&","(",")","*",",","-",".","/",":",";","<","=",">","?","@","[","]","^","_","`","{","|","}","~","0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [`random.choices`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices):

```
 password = divider.join(random.choices(chars, k=letters))
```

Comment: Damn, Thats easy. It woks too so Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, learn to love the docs =) They are quite good usually. Even code completion in the shell will often show you the way.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `random.choices` for choosing many characters at once without using a loop:

```
>>> random.choices(['a', 'b', 'c'], k=20)
['a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b']
```

EDIT: just saw the other answer was edited :/